# Switch Chrome profile using the keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome

I have multiple profiles set up in Chrome, and I find myself switching quite often. Is there a keyboard shortcut or something that I can use to switch between them without needing the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Google support](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171571):

For Windows and Linux users

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

and for Mac OS

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

brings up the drop-down menu for multiple users in Chrome. Then the user can use the arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select a user.